# 404 error but file displays in browser ok

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I posted last night getting some help with a 500 error on a PHP script used by AJAX on my site. With some help I found the 500 was springing from the include (DOCUMENT_ROOT wasn't serving the expected path, hence the 500).

Now this issue is fixed I've moved straight into the next one :(   Can anyone tell me why the following file shows the correct code in the Firebug output response, but springs a 404 in the console and fails to feed my AJAX script?

```
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sac-active-wp/wp-blog-header.php');

$pagetitle = $_POST;
$value = array_shift($pagetitle);

$thequery = 'title_li=&parent='.$value.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=ASC'; 
$display = wp_list_pages($thequery);
echo $display;
?>
```

As ever, thanks in advance folks. Help's always appreciated!
Graham

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue myself! Should anyone else encounter a similar issue here's the cause and solution:

404 error sprang because I called in the Wordpress header to allow plugin style development externally. The header included is incorrect, hence the 404. To remedy this, simply replace the include line with the following:

```
require('/path/to/your/wp-config.php');
$wp->init();
$wp->parse_request();
$wp->query_posts();
$wp->register_globals();
```

This bypasses the 404 without the header hackfixes sometimes found (they're not ideal for SEO!)

Hope this helps somebody along the way :)

Thanks,
Graham